# How can i set image above another image in android?

Tags: android

I am new in android.
I want to set my image above another image.

If you want to see how? please, click on this link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tndev.loveframes&hl=en

Comment: i edit my post and set link click on link and tell me

Answer (score 0):

You may use different ImageViews and place then one above the other in a RelativeLayout. This can be done only if you know the count of images you need to show.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/firstIV"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondIV"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstIV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: will you give me some initial idea to do this things?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used FrameLayout, FrameLayout is the answer for your Query in my case i am displaying a checkbox above an image same.

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_check_box_unselected" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/f_register_ss_checkbox_send_me_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:button="@null" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please see the my post link then after told me because i am new for android

Comment: add another imageView below of your imageView in this FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Main Imageview in framelayout like this

```
  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/Frm_imgEditing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and In activity code,
add another Imageview for Frame

```
FrameLayout mainFrm = (FrameLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.Frm_imgEditing);
ImageView  border_view = new ImageView(getActivity());

border_view.setId(R.id.border_view);
mainFrm.addView(border_view);

SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(mActivity.getResources(), R.raw.your_Frame_svg__id);
Bitmap bitmap = Utility.drawableToBitmap(svg.createPictureDrawable());
border_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
border_view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

In this code, use svg image for better performance.

Comment: Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)  is a one type of image type https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=what+is+svg

Comment: sample svg link http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/download/infrared_here_symbol_black_on_transparent_clip_art_25509.html

You can also use png image like this  R.drawble.your_png

Comment: for use svg image , you should import library for svg.
but, you can also use png image,try png image